# script in solaris to send mail when file systems reaches prescribed threshold value

Tags: shell, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
threshold="1"
{
        >/tmp/output
        for fs in $(df -hk | awk '{print $6}' | sed '1 d'); do
                chk=$(df -hk ${fs} | sed '1 d' | awk '{print $5}' | awk -F\% '{print $1}')
                if [ "${chk}" -gt "${threshold}" ]; then
                        echo "$(hostname): Alert Fileystem ${fs} is above ${threshold}%." >>/tmp/output
                fi
        done
        cat /tmp/output| mailx -s "sub" abc@.com
}
```

Now if a fs crosses the threshold limit, we should get mail

Comment: If the code works but you need improvement, you should go to Code Review Stackexchange.

Comment: I guess you don't want to send an email if `/tmp/output` is empty?

Comment: the code is working perfectly. I tested it, high space in the sense files with occupying more space in the filesystem and yes i dont want to send a mail if /tmp/output is empty

Comment: You are not expecting a answer with how to write a script that shows the large files sorted in a filesystem. So why this title?

Comment: the question is now edited correctly can you review my question and clear the flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion how you could do it. See the comments in the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# define constants on top so you can find and edit them easily
declare -ri threshold=1
declare -r mailsubject="[$(hostname)] FS Alert Exceed ${threshold}%"
declare -r mailbodystart="$(hostname) Filesystem Alert, threshold=${threshold}%\n"
declare -r mailto="abc@.com"

# use variable instead of output file
declare mailbody=""

for fs in $(df -hk | awk '{print $6}' | sed '1d'); do
        chk=$(df -hk ${fs} | sed '1d' | awk '{print $5}' | awk -F\% '{print $1}')
        if [ "$chk" -gt "$threshold" ]; then
                # append to mailbody
                mailbody="${mailbody}${chk}% ${fs}\n"
        fi
done

# send mail if mailbody is non-empty
if [ -n "$mailbody" ]; then
        # sort by filesystem size, largest first
        mailbody=$(echo -e "$mailbody" | sort -nr)
        echo -e "${mailbodystart}${mailbody}" | mailx -s "$mailsubject" "$mailto"
fi
```

Comment: I want to add Thanks and regards and under it my name in the mailbody, tried different combinations using /t and /n but didnt work, can you help me out